# I want to use useRef() to access an element in a reat-leaflet and use the Flyto function. However, useRef returns "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-leaflet

I've never written javascript, typescript, or React until recently, so I apologize if my question is confusing.

（I'm omitting some parts because it's my work code.）
I want the angle to be moved by handleOnflyTo when the Button is clicked as shown below.

```js
import React, { VFC, useRef } from "react"
import { useResizeDetector } from 'react-resize-detector';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, CircleMarker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import { MapDatum } from "./types"
import L from 'leaflet'
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

type MapProps = {
  mapData: MapDatum[]
}

// Another Implementation Candidate https://medium.com/react-courses/world-map-chart-with-react-d3-with-ts-468b05f35404

export const MapContent: VFC<MapProps> = ({ mapData }) => {
  const { ref, width, height } = useResizeDetector()
  const mapRef = useRef<L.Map>()
  const disneyLandLatLng = {lat:33.8121, lng:-117.9190}

  function handleOnFlyTo() {
    console.log(mapRef.current)
    mapRef.current?.flyTo(disneyLandLatLng, 14, {
      duration: 2
    });
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <Button onClick={handleOnFlyTo}>Fly</Button>
      {!!(width && height) &&
        <MapContainer
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          bounds={[[-180, -270], [180, 270]]}
          center={[0, 0]}
          zoom={1}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          attributionControl={false}
          whenCreated={ mapInstance => { mapRef.current = mapInstance }}
        >
        <TileLayer
          attribution=""
          // From https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Stadia.AlidadeSmoothDark
          url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
        />
        {mapData.map(({ label, lon, lat, r, color }, i) => (
          <CircleMarker
            key={i}
            center={[lat, lon]}
            radius={r}
            fillColor={color}
            stroke={false}
            fillOpacity={.6} >

            <Popup>
              {label}
            </Popup>
          </CircleMarker>
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/841

From this issue, I learned that in react-leaflet v3, api can be called directly from `mapRef.current` without accessing `leafletElement`, and `whenCreated` in MapContainer is effective.

However, when I actually ran it, I confirmed that `mapRef.current` is **undifined** in `console.log()` within `handleOnFlyTo`.
Naturally, the next `FlyTo` will not be executed either.
How can I make sure that mapRef is not **undefined**?

Answer (score 0):

The React way to do this is to nest your flyTo button inside the map container and access `map` with `useMap()` hook:

```
const FlyToButton = ({ latlng }) => {
  const map = useMap(); // available when component nested inside MapContainer
  const fly = () => {
    map.flyTo(latlng, 14, { duration: 2 });
  }
  return <button onClick={fly}>Fly</button>
}

export const MapContent: VFC<MapProps> = ({ mapData }) => {
  const { ref, width, height } = useResizeDetector();
  const disneyLandLatLng = {lat:33.8121, lng:-117.9190}

  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      {!!(width && height) &&
        <MapContainer
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          bounds={[[-180, -270], [180, 270]]}
          center={[0, 0]}
          zoom={1}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          attributionControl={false}
          whenCreated={ mapInstance => { mapRef.current = mapInstance }}
        >
        <FlyToButton latlng={disneyLandLatLng} />
        ...
```

You will need to use CSS positioning and zIndex to place button at the top of the map.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I did get ANGLE to work!
I still have a problem to solve, however.

With this solution, the buttons are overlapped with the map.
What should I do if I want to display it in a different place from the Map?

2. I've fixed the destination of FlyTo to test, but I want to be able to fly to various places.
If I want to do so, should I update the value passed as an argument with useState or something?

Comment: I think you want to follow this https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/ . Make sure to useMemo for MapContainer, otherwise it will re-render repeatedly and whenCreated will be called many times. You don't want that. Also, note that you do not use a ref but a state variable inside whenCreated